# can not roslauunch Turtlebot in Docker container

Tags: docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello~ all

I create a docker to quickly setup ROS-indigo and Turtlebot packages on Ubuntu.
I have Turtlebot PC and Remote PC.
After testing, this docker works well on Remote PC to interact with Turtlebot PC.
But unfortunately , if I run this docker on my Turtlebot PC, it's failed and shows some Error messages.

```
[ERROR] [1498784075.788970033]: Zeroconf: failed to create an avahi client.
zeroconf: client.c:785: avahi_client_get_state: Assertion `client' failed.
[zeroconf/zeroconf-13] process has died [pid 499, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/zeroconf_avahi/zeroconf      
__name:=zeroconf __log:=/root/.ros/log/ae0eabf0-5d2e-11e7-a39a-0242ac110001/zeroconf-zeroconf-13.log].
```

does anybody know how to solve this ??
Thank you

---

After running "roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch", the error message is shown as follows:

```
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [322]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://172.17.0.1:11311

setting /run_id to ae0eabf0-5d2e-11e7-a39a-0242ac110001
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [335]
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [353]
process[diagnostic_aggregator-3]: started with pid [354]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4]: started with pid [355]
process[mobile_base-5]: started with pid [356]
process[bumper2pointcloud-6]: started with pid [357]
process[cmd_vel_mux-7]: started with pid [358]
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-8]: started with pid [359]
process[capability_server-9]: started with pid [360]
process[app_manager-10]: started with pid [421]
process[master-11]: started with pid [436]
process[interactions-12]: started with pid [468]
process[zeroconf/zeroconf-13]: started with pid [499]

[ERROR] [1498784075.788970033]: Zeroconf: failed to create an avahi client.

zeroconf: client.c:785: avahi_client_get_state: Assertion `client' failed.


[zeroconf/zeroconf-13] process has died [pid 499, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/zeroconf_avahi/zeroconf      
__name:=zeroconf __log:=/root/.ros/log/ae0eabf0-5d2e-11e7-a39a-0242ac110001/zeroconf-zeroconf-13.log].
log file: /root/.ros/log/ae0eabf0-5d2e-11e7-a39a-0242ac110001/zeroconf-zeroconf-13*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265195/can-not-roslauunch-turtlebot-in-docker-container/) by [Eric_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25481/eric_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Eric,

As you saw in http://answers.ros.org/question/203725/problems-launching-rocon-chatter-concert-inside-of-a-docker-image/, the issue is that Zeroconf doesn't work in Docker.
You can Google for "zeroconf docker" to find solutions for this issue, or use the patch to rocon that Jihoon posted on the other question to modify the concert to not use docker.
Unfortunately either solution will require you to search, learn and work a little to make it work.

Good luck!
Julian

---

Originally posted by [jcerruti](https://answers.ros.org/users/19864/jcerruti/) with karma: 113 on 2017-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0